# Code I can't make work - is it a JSF bug?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-7, mojarra

I am not able to make something work that I think should. I posted a week ago but have not had any replies [accessing a list within a list in p:datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316607/accessing-a-list-within-a-list-in-pdatatable?noredirect=1#comment35705463_23316607).

This is the same question but with specific code that demonstrates the problem. By making P1 editable and P2 display you can see that the property is changed without user input. I believe it is a system bug but hope I am wrong as I really need this to work. Here is the code:

```
    <h:body>
    <h:form>   
        <p:selectOneButton value="#{test.selectedIndex}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="0"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="1"/>
            <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form" listener="#{test.doNothingAjax()}"/> 
        </p:selectOneButton>

        <p:panelGrid>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>Name</p:column>
                <p:column>Selected Index</p:column>
                <p:column>P1</p:column>
                <p:column>P2</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <c:forEach items="#{test.list}" var="item2">
                <c:set value="#{test.getMinor(item2)}" var="sub"/>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>#{item2.name}</p:column>
                    <p:column>${test.selectedIndex}</p:column>
                    <p:column><p:inputText value="#{sub.p1}"/></p:column>
                    <p:column>#{sub.p2}</p:column>
                </p:row>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and The JAVA
    @ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Test {

```
private List<ItemHolder> list;
private int selectedIndex=0;

public Test() {
    list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new ItemHolder());
}

public void doNothingAjax() {
}

public Item getMinor(ItemHolder holder) {
    return holder.getItems().get(selectedIndex);
}
//Getters & Setters

public class ItemHolder {

    private String name;
    List<Item> items;

    public ItemHolder() {
        name = "Test";
        items = new ArrayList();
        items.add(new Item("index 0",0,0));
        items.add(new Item("index 1",1,1));            
    }
    //getters and setters

public class Item {
    private String label;
    private int p1; //property 1
    private int p2; //property 2

    public Item(String label, int p1, int p2) {
        this.label = label;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If it is a system bug any suggestions for a workaround would also be helpful. I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks, John

Comment: Just edit the original question instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing a list within a list in p:datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316607/accessing-a-list-within-a-list-in-pdatatable)

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't getting any traction and I thought something complete and straight-forward might be better than just making the other excessively long. As per your comment, the other post is updated.